# Reading inputs from Mac aggregate device separately

Tags: mac, audio, sox

I understand how to create an aggregate device and have seen tutorials on how to record each input to a separate track on garage band. What I am curious about is if there is any library or utility that allows access to data coming from only one input of the aggregate device. I would assume that there is a way to pipe each track into my program individually but am struggling to turn up any instruction on this.

I know it is a bit of a rare ask but figured I might get lucky and run across someone on here that knows a little more than myself

Comment: I'd say it depends on how the devices present to the app & how the app can handle that - which I'm aware is really vague ;) Could you post a pic of your Audio MDI setup showing the aggregate channeling & also one of GarageBand's input device selector. [As I don't actually use either Aggregate inputs or GarageBand, I use ASIO & Cubase, I'm trying to see if I can figure it out from first principles ;)

Comment: Thanks, I think I am going to go a different route with this and just use an audio device that has more input channels. I appreciate the look though